# Changes made to a pointer inside a fixed block retain or not?

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, unity-game-engine, native-code

Please have a look at the following c# code:

```
    double* ptr;

    fixed(double* vrt_ptr = &vertices[0])
    {
        fixed(int* tris_ptr = &tris[0])
        {
            ptr = compute(vrt_ptr, 5, (double*)tris_ptr, 5);
// compute() is a native C++ function 
        }
    }

    Debug.Log("Vertices Recieved: " + *ptr);
/* and so on */
```

I am having garbage value from *ptr. I have a suspicion that the array assigned to `ptr` by `compute` doesn't retain outside fixed block. Is it so?? Or is it due to some other problem?

Comment: Probably, `compute` returns a pointer to a local variable, destroyed when the function returns. But there's no way to know without seeing the function.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Local variable's pointer won't be destroyed as soon as the method returns. isn't it?

Comment: Oh.. yes, that's a vector<double>. How can I retain that memory? Using Dynamic allocation??

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: A local variable will be destroyed when the program leaves its scope, and any pointers to it will be left pointing to garbage.

Comment: @CashifIlyas: In standard C++, you'd return the vector. I've no idea whether that's possible in whatever mixture of languages you're using.

Comment: @MikeSeymour It seems `compute` is c++ method. I think this is [relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/2530848). I may be wrong. Correct me if am wrong.

Comment: Does `compute` allocate memory? If so, how? Does it take GC into consideration?

Comment: @JeffRSon compute is a c++ function, and it returns a reference to a vector, which now I have known will be pointing to garbage on return. So I think I should allocate memory inside compute. right?

Comment: I think it would be better to allocate it before calling `compute` and hand it over to it. Such you could get rid of the spurious `ptr` and it would be more clear if you release the memory later on (in order to prevent a memory leak).

Comment: @JeffRSon Thanks, gonna try it :)

Answer (score 3):

This is **not** valid code, the garbage collector can only update the value of the `vrt_ptr` and `tris_ptr` variables.  But the unmanaged code uses a *copy* of these pointers, the value of the copy cannot be updated by the GC.  So if a garbage collection occurs *while* the unmanaged code is running, possible for example when other threads in the program trigger a collection, then the unmanaged code will read garbage data through the pointer copy.  Very hard to diagnose, it doesn't happen very often.

You **must** pin the vertices and tris arrays.  In your case already ably done by the pinvoke marshaller, simply by passing the arrays directly without using *fixed*.  Fix:

```
   double* ptr = compute(vertices, 5, tris, 5);
```

Adjust the pinvoke declaration accordingly, replacing double* with double[].

You'll now also have to the deal with the likely reason you wrote this code in the first place.  There is *no* scenario where casting an int[] to double[] is ever valid, the likely reason you got a garbage result early before that GC disaster could strike.  If you can't update the declaration of *tris* for some reason then you must create a double[] before the call.